# UploadOperation timeout restrictions

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

[UploadOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.uploadoperation.aspx) has next time restrictions:

> 1.) When establishing a new connection for an upload over TCP/SSL, the connection attempt is aborted if not established within five minutes.
>
> 2.) After the connection has been established, an HTTP request message that has not received a response within two minutes is aborted.

Is it normal for POST and PUT requests to limit them in time(if I want to upload big file)?

Is there a way to overwrite that "two minutes" value to allow longer requests?

Comment: Have you verified that connections are aborted if 2 minutes are exceeded? This timeout should only apply if there are two minutes between the end of the request and the beginning of the response.

Comment: Sure, it is aborted exactly 2 minutes after start of upload.

Comment: Maybe a timeout in the server?

Answer (score 0):

The `0x80072EE2` exception is `ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT`. That happens because the server has not read data from the request in 2 minutes, or because the server has not sent response data in 2 minutes.

If the server keeps reading or writing data constantly, the connection does not timeout.